# Deserialise JSON with dynamic field

Tags: android, json

I'm loading JSON with a completely dynamic field from an API using Retrofit on Android.

This is an example:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "messages": {
        "success": [
            "SUCCESS_MESSAGE"
        ],
        "error": {
            "specific_error": {
                …
            }
        }
    },
    "session": {
        "id": "fj4qewqrewq43fdsa",
        "expire": null,
        "YII_CSRF_TOKEN": "fda432fdafasd78978fdas"
    },
    "metadata": {…}
}
```

The structure of the messages object can change with every request. Sometimes there is the success field and sometimes not. Same goes for the error field. The error field especially can be an array but also an object with several other objects and fields inside.

Does it make sense to deserialise the messages field into different POJOs and if so how would I do that? Would it make more sense to keep the field as a JSON object and get values from the object when they are needed?

Comment: Just deserialise into the same object. And check if `success` or `error` is null.

Comment: Your comment made me think about it in a different way. I think I have found a way to get what I need without having to write a custom  deserialiser for every possible structure that the API throws at me in the `error` field.